# RegEx: Match portion of config string (by defined region)

Tags: regex

I need to isolate a portion of a string after the key `%CONFIG\n`. Trailing newlines and other regions that begin with `%` shall be stripped.

My example string:

```
Configuration File

Format
<Identifier>: <init> <start> <end> <step>

%CONFIG
Line A: 0 1000 5000 300
Line B: 0 0 200 20



%OPTIONAL_OTHER_KEY

some other definitions
```

where the only match should be:

```
Line A: 0 1000 5000 300
Line B: 0 0 200 20
```

Take everything after and including `%OPTIONAL_OTHER_KEY` as optional content of the input string, which shall not be included in the match.

I've got already `(?<=%CONFIG\n)[\w\W]*(?=%)`, but it does not strip trailing new-lines...

Comment: Then try lazy matching: [`(?<=%CONFIG\n)[\w\W]*?(?=\s*%)`](https://regex101.com/r/vK6oH0/3)

Comment: That was quick and correct! Thank you. Could you post it as a solution, so that I can confirm it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you need to leave out some whitespace from the match, the generic subpattern that comes right *before* should be used with a lazy quantifier (if other means are not working), and the whitespace subpattern must be used with a greedy quantifier (well, in some languages, you should not mix lazy and greedy quantifiers, as in Tcl, I hope it is not the case here). It is something can be implemented quickly, but might require adjusting if any performance issues occur.

So, you can use

```
(?<=%CONFIG\n)[\w\W]*?(?=\s*%)
                     ^   ^^^
```

See [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/vK6oH0/3)

Here, `[\w\W]*?` is used with `*?` lazy quantifier matching *zero or more any characters but as few as possible*. `\s*` matching zero or more whitespace characters, as many as possible, is added to the lookahead so that it is not part of the match.

However, **if you do not have `%` after `%CONFIG`, you need to use an *unrolled* lazy quantifier version**.

```
(?<=%CONFIG\n)\S*(?:\s+[^\s%]\S*)*
```

See [the demo](https://regex101.com/r/vK6oH0/5)

Comment: Actually, the best regex for it is something like [`(?<=%CONFIG\n)\S*(?:\s[^\s%]\S*)*`](https://regex101.com/r/vK6oH0/4).

Comment: The second approach might be more robust, but it does'nt match all lines, if `Line A` ends with a space character.

Comment: I just noticed, that your proposed expression does'nt match the substring correctly, if no `%` follows the `%CONFIG`-region.

Comment: That is what I thought: XY problem. Are the requirements set finally now?

Comment: Other regions are optional only. I can still define that the file has to end with `%END` or something similar, but I'd prefer not to do so. `(?<=%CONFIG\n)([\w\W]*?)(?=\s*(%|$))` seems to be a bit better...

Comment: It would be great to have your sample inputs to test against. Please try `(?<=%CONFIG\n)\S*(?:\s+[^\s%]\S*)*`

Comment: That works, too. I'll take it for now. My above-mentioned sample actually covers it. Just take everything after and including `%OPTIONAL_OTHER_KEY` as optional content of the string.

Comment: I really hope you have got it right now as I lost track of what you actually might need to match. If you need to match that `%OPTIONAL_OTHER_KEY` as part of the match, the [pattern will get more complicated](https://regex101.com/r/yB5vE1/1).

Comment: Now I've got, what I wanted :). The next key (if exists) shall not be part of the match. Thank you very much for your help!